# VBA Code to select Sender and Signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

In Excel I'm using code like this to begin an e-mail message through Outlook:

```
Set mOutlookApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.application")
Set OutMail = mOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = "blahblah@blah.com"
    .Subject = "More BLAH here"
    .HTMLBody = "Message Text" & .HTMLBody ' This preserves the Signature in the message.
    .Display
End With
```

Normally, when I send a (manual) e-mail, I can choose to send it from an address other than my normal one (by pressing the "From" button).

Also, I can choose from one of several signatures I have saved.

How can I accomplish these feats in VBA code?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property, call `Display` (at that point Outlook will insert the signature), read the `HTMLBody` property (it will now contain the signature), merge it with your own data (note that 2 HTML strings cannot be simply concatenated), set the `HTMLBody` property.

Answer (score 1):

Change `1` to the account number from which you want to send

```
.SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
```

As far as the signatures are concerned, they are stored in `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures` you can loop through the signatures and choose the relevant one