# Specific outlook signature depending on subject field

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, signature

I have the code beneath and would like some help.
The code makes sure that when I send customer satisfaction mails I don't spam them with mails. Therefore this makes sure that I only send it one time per month for each customer because the customer name will be in the subject. They are in the seperate folder named "customersatisfaction".
The problem is that whenever I send these emails I want it to automatically choose a specific signature. Right now it chooses the default signature but I have another one for these specific emails. 
Is there a way to set up a signature so it is automatically selected when the subject field is something like "customer satisfaction mail"?

```
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal thisItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olfolder As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object


Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set firstFolder = olNs.Folders("customermail@mads.com") ' name of my shared inbox
Set olfolder = firstFolder.Folders("Customersatisfaction")

  ' iterate thru emails
 For Each Item In olfolder.Items
       ' check subject content & date difference
    If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.Subject) And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then
          ' added this part
          If MsgBox("Ths email has been sent this month. Will you send again?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
            ' cancel the email
            Cancel = True
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
End sub
```

Edit:
Here is the updated code. I have now moved the new part down.

```
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal thisItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olfolder As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strSignatureFile As String
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim strSignature As String

 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set firstFolder = olNs.Folders("customermail@mads.com") ' name of my shared inbox
 Set olfolder = firstFolder.Folders("Customersatisfaction")

  If InStr(Item.Subject, "Customer saticfaction") Then 
 strSignatureFile = "*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Customersatisfaction.htm" 
'Read the specific signature file 
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strSignatureFile) strSignature = objTextStream.ReadAll 
'Insert the signature to this email 
objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<HTML><BODY><br>" & strSignature & "</br></HTML></BODY>" 
End If

 ' iterate thru emails
  For Each Item In olfolder.Items
       ' check subject content & date difference
      If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.Subject) And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then
       ' added this part
          If MsgBox("Ths email has been sent this month. Will you send again?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
           ' cancel the email
         Cancel = True
      End If
If InStr(Item.Subject, "Customer saticfaction") Then 
  strSignatureFile = "%usrprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Customersatisfaction.htm" 
   'Read the specific signature file 
   Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
   Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strSignatureFile)
  strSignature = objTextStream.ReadAll 
    'Insert the signature to this email 
  objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<HTML><BODY><br>" & strSignature & "</br></HTML></BODY>" 
  End If
        Exit For
    End If
   End sub
```

Comment: According with this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858921/7558682) you can loop through the folder which contains the signatures and choose the one you need. [Here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-select-different-signatures-different-recipients-outlook-emails/) is a way to do so.

Comment: I have tried adding the following, but I it is not working for me. Am I doing something wrong? If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.Subject) = "Customer saticfaction" Then
        strSignatureFile = "*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Customersatisfaction.htm"
         End If

Comment: You missed the part on read the specific signature file and insert the signature file.

Comment: Ahh thank you - now it is giving me error 91 here: If InStr(Item.Subject, "Customer saticfaction") Then
        strSignatureFile = "*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Customersatisfaction.htm"
            'Read the specific signature file
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strSignatureFile)
    strSignature = objTextStream.ReadAll
 
    'Insert the signature to this email
    objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<HTML><BODY><br>" & strSignature & "</br></HTML></BODY>"
         End If

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57952399/edit) your question with the new code and specify in which line gives you the error...

Answer (score 0):

Here, your problem explained through the code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal thisItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olfolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strSignatureFile As String
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim objTextStream As Object
    Dim strSignature As String

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set firstFolder = olNs.Folders("customermail@mads.com") ' name of my shared inbox
    Set olfolder = firstFolder.Folders("Customersatisfaction")
    'This next line gives me error 91. This happens because the object item is empty, won't be set till later
'    If InStr(Item.Subject, "Customer saticfaction") Then
'        strSignatureFile = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE")) & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Customersatisfaction.htm"
'        'Read the specific signature file
'        Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'        Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strSignatureFile) strSignature = objTextStream.ReadAll
'        'Insert the signature to this email
'        objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<HTML><BODY><br>" & strSignature & "</br></HTML></BODY>"
'    End If

     ' iterate thru emails
    For Each Item In olfolder.Items
        'here your Item object has a subject
        If InStr(Item.Subject, "Customer saticfaction") Then
            strSignatureFile = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE")) & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Customersatisfaction.htm"
            'Read the specific signature file
            Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strSignatureFile) strSignature = objTextStream.ReadAll
            'Insert the signature to this email
            objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<HTML><BODY><br>" & strSignature & "</br></HTML></BODY>"
        End If

         ' check subject content & date difference
        If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.Subject) And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then
         ' added this part
            If MsgBox("Ths email has been sent this month. Will you send again?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
             ' cancel the email
           Cancel = True
        End If
        'this exit for will stop your loop after the first item in any case.
        Exit For
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay so I need to move it down in the code so it has an object item?

Comment: You have the object, but the object is empty until you start looping through here: `For Each Item in olfolder.Items`. From here your `Item` object won't be empty.

Comment: Perfect - I have now updated the file but now nothing happens. It still uses the default signature. Sorry for all te questions and thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Debug your code to see if it does what you need... You can debug by pressing F8 will exectue one line of code at a time.

Comment: It doesn't come with an error or anything when i'm trying this. Nothing really happens...